# Twillo Nodejs Call Busy Redial

Tags: node.js, twilio

Hey everyone I'm new and need some help. What I'm trying to do is this:

1. Make a Call to a phone number.
2. If call is busy keep calling until not busy.
3. Once connected call a number and connect the current call.

If you can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Here is what I have so far

```
"use strict";

const twilio = require('twilio');
const client = new twilio();
client.calls.create({
  url: 'http://something.ngrok.io/voice',
  to: '+1',
  from: '+1',
  statusCallback: 'http://something.grok.io/events',
  statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
  statusCallbackEvent: ['initiated', 'ringing', 'answered', 'completed'],
}, (err, call) => {
  if(err) { console.log(err); return err; }
  process.stdout.write(call.sid);
});
```